# Keep the same distance between the camera and a canvas

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The idea is to move the camera to a certain point in front of a canvas. I've positioned the camera for the first canvas and I need to maintain this distance when the camera moves to another canvase (the canvases are equal, they just have different positions and rotation angles).

So the question is how to maintain the same camera distance from the canvas centre?

[image: Just to show the idea]

Comment: Mandatory "what have you tried so far?" comment? Surely you can find the normal of the canvas, and use that to compute a position at a given distance that the camera should reside at?

Comment: @john yeah, sorry I'm not using my own laptop right now and I can't copy the code right now. All I'm looking for is a hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this script on a gameObject(like the camera).
Assign the **camera**, **canvases** and **distance** variable.
Hope this helps:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class CanvasPositioner : MonoBehaviour {
    public Camera cam;
    public Canvas[] canvases;
    public float distance = 15;

    private float xPos;
    private float yPos;
    private float zPos;
    private float angle;

    void PositionCanvases(){
        for(int i = 0; i < canvases.Length; i++){
            angle = canvases[i].transform.eulerAngles.y;
            xPos = cam.transform.position.x + distance * Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad* angle);
            yPos = cam.transform.position.y;
            zPos = cam.transform.position.z + distance * Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle);
            canvases[i].transform.position = new Vector3(xPos,yPos,zPos);
        }
    }
    void LateUpdate () {
        PositionCanvases();
    }
}
```

Comment: Used basic trigonometry in this. If you want, you can read here: https://math.libretexts.org/Core/Precalculus/Chapter_5%3A_Trigonometric_Functions_of_Angles/5.3_Points_on_Circles_using_Sine_and_Cosine

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate. It helped

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the orientation of the canvas. If you orient them like a square

---

|__| you could simply place the cam in the exact middleand transform by 90°

If you need a different distance, move them further apart and do it something like this

/          \
 |      ○     | on the circle in the middle, you can move the camera on the outer edge. The canvas orientation needs to be in parallel to the closest tangent of the circle. You can make it move on the curveline by having an imaginary (or empty gameobject) in the middle and maintain the distance from that.

Comment: The canvases are positioned at 0, 45, 90 degrees with the same Y position and different X and Z

Comment: Oh ignore the drawings in my reply, the editor butchered them.

Comment: How is the canvas transform pos stored? Is it its center or vertex?

Comment: I'm not following...whay do you mean by stored? I access canvases and their position through the class declaration in the main game object they're all attached to...or it's not the question?

Comment: What value does the canvas position store? Its center?

Comment: Do you mean canvas pivot or canvas itselft? If pivot, then it's center at the bottom. I did that so the scaling for different resolutions was correct. If you mean the canvas itself then I don't know just somewhere in the scene 515, 0, 0...I guess

Comment: Let us assume it is the center. You could simply define 3 equidistant points (equidistant.. so grown up) that are on the tangent of each canvas center. Then, you simply change both pos and rotation of camera